# Using .exists? in view

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, exists

I am creating an Open House feature. I am wanting to check the DB to see if there has been an Open House created for a specific listing using .exists? but the item I am trying to display is displaying on all of the listings, not just the ones that have open houses. I currently have the .exists? code in my view, not sure if that is the best way to do it, but not sure how to do it any other way. Any help is appreciated.

```
<% if OpenHouse.exists? %><span class="label label-yellow">Upcoming Open House</span> <% end %>
```

Comment: writing it either in `application_helper.rb` or `some_helper.rb` is the recommend way. avoid using SQL on view side. You can simply create a function and call it the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pragmatically - you can, but it's not a good thing to use `SQL` queries in `view`, you can at least move this query to `helper` or read about `presenters` layer, you can check out this `railscast` it will help to clean up your views. http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch?view=comments